# How to navigate to a web form programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, contentplaceholder

How I can navigate to a web form on button click?

I have a datagrid with user information. I want to open an asp.net web form in the same master pages content place holder, when the user clicks on a row .

Any advice?

Comment: You could search [SO](http://stackoverflow.com) and get a variety of answers to this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Response.Redirect("secondpage.aspx"). This redirects to that page. Save the row number, id, etc. in the session state like Session["rowid"] = 1 or send it as a querystring like secondpage.aspx?rowid=23. You need to save the row information and get that rowid from the second page and load the information for that row.

Answer (score 0):

whithin the button tag : PostBackUrl="~/TargetPage.aspx"